# math.random with multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Im simply trying to out.print an specific range from the animal array. I've tried 3 different ways, (hint) the code that I commented out. The print statement always prints bear. How do I fix this?

```
String animal[][] = {
        {"bear","lion","wolf","panther"},
        {"alligator","komododragon","spyro the dragon","turtle"},
        {"great white","clown fish","hammer head","Nessi"},
        {"blue jay","red jay","eagle","crow"},
    };

    int x = (int) Math.random() * (2 - 0);
    int y = (int) Math.random() * (4 - 0);  

    //String yourAniaml = animal[(int) Math.random() * (2-0) ][(int) Math.random() * (4-0)];
//  System.out.println(animal[(int) Math.random() * (2-0) ][(int) Math.random() * (4-0)]);
    System.out.println( animal[x][y] );
```

Comment: Make sure to cast after multiplying, not before. Also not sure why you are doing `- 0`. So you can do something like `int x = (int) (Math.random() * 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the result of `Math.random() * foo`, not just `Math.random()`:

```
int x = (int) (Math.random() * (2 - 0));
int y = (int) (Math.random() * (4 - 0));
```

The reason for this is that `Math.random()` always returns a number in the range 0 ≤ x < 1, so `(int) Math.random()` will always be `0`, and zero times anything is zero.

Answer (score 0):

assuming 0,2 is your range for x
and 0,4 is your range for y

```
int x = (int) (Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
int y = (int) (Math.random() * (4 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
```